# Can't get `router.navigate` to navigate

Tags: angular

I've been having trouble figuring out how I can protect a route from direct access, and found that `Resolve` triggers each time a component is accessed. I created the following Resolver:

```
export class LoginResolver implements Resolve<Boolean> {

    constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Boolean> {
        return this.userService.watchCurrentUser().map((currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser !== null) {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                return null;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

As far as I can see, the resolver works. If I log the data, it shows me what I expect, however, even when the first if statement is successful (tested by adding a lot instead the if block), the page doesn't navigate away. I've basically copied the code out of the router tutorial, so not sure what I'm missing. Is there an obvious mistake?

Comment: That's the role of a CanActivate guard. Not the role of a Resolve. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: I thought Resolve was used for getting data when accessing a route? Even the Angular Router documentation shows a resolve that routes based on the data that returns. Plus, CanActivate doesn't get hit if you directly access a route, while Resolve does.

Comment: It is used to do that, yes. But you're trying to use one to prevent navigation to the route instead. Not to load data. Preventing access to a route is what a CanActivate guard is for.

Comment: Well, I need to first get the data, so resolve will be used for that. Regardless of if I'm using it correctly or not, and I'll be glad to change it, that doesn't answer why navigate isn't working. It's an example in the Angular docs, which tells me it should work, even if I shouldn't code it that way. And as I said before, CanActivate doesn't prevent direct access to path (by entering it into an address bar).